# in yii how to perform dynamic validation based on the dropdown choice

Tags: yii

Hello everybody and thansk for reading .

Iam making a website just for fun and to learn yii. The website is a app that can be used for reporting pirated links.

I have an input filed in which i provide a link and than i have a dropdown menu from where you can select the type of link you are submitting. Depending on the value you select i want different validation rules to perform on the link submitted. If i was not clear in my explenation feel free to visit www.youtubetv.it , on the main page you will see a input field and a dropdown.

The code is as follows ;

```
   <div class="span4">
    <div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on" style="height: 50px;">
            <i class="icon-4x icon-globe" style="line-height: 54px;"></i></span>
        <?php
        echo $form->textField($model, 'link', array(
            'prepend' => '<i class="icon-4x icon-globe" style="line-height: 54px;"></i>',
            'class' => 'span12', 'maxlength' => 999,
            'style' => 'height:60px;font-size: 22px;width: 400px;',
        ));
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="span4 offset1">
    <?php
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'category', CHtml::listData(Lookup::model()->findAll('type="kind"'), 'code', 'name'), array(
        'prompt' => 'Select Type',
        'class' => 'span12',
        'style' => 'height:60px;font-size: 22px;',
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Current validation rules in the model

```
public function rules() {
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('category, link', 'required'),
        array('id_user', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
        array('link', 'length', 'max' => 999),
        array('link', 'url',
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'defaultScheme' => null,
            //'pattern' => 'esspressione regolare',
            'message' => 'The specified model does not exist.',
            'validSchemes' => (array('http', 'https'))
        ),
        array('category, web_page', 'length', 'max' => 255),
        array('creation_date', 'default',
            'value' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
            'setOnEmpty' => false,
            'on' => 'insert'),
        array('id_public_link, category, id_user, link, creation_date', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
    );
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could show me an example of how i could validate the "url" if someone selects Movie from the dropdown list.

please feel free to ask for clarification if i was not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii has so called *scenario* for validation rules, what you need is to add 'on' key with any scenario name you like as a value in a rule you want. And then set scenario for your model as $model->scenario = 'Your scenario';
e.g.

```
public function rules() {
// NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
// will receive user inputs.
return array(
    array('category, link', 'required'),
    array('id_user', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
    array('link', 'length', 'max' => 999),
    array('link', 'url',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'defaultScheme' => null,
        //'pattern' => 'esspressione regolare',
        'message' => 'The specified model does not exist.',
        'validSchemes' => (array('http', 'https')),
        'on'=>'urlcheck'
    ),
    array('category, web_page', 'length', 'max' => 255),
    array('creation_date', 'default',
        'value' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
        'setOnEmpty' => false,
        'on' => 'insert'),
    array('id_public_link, category, id_user, link, creation_date', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
    );
}
```

And then in your action use:

```
...
$type = isset($_POST['Lookup']['type'])?$_POST['Lookup']['type']:false;
if($type === '1') //as I assume from your website '1' is a Movie
    $model->scenario = 'urlcheck';
...
```

Btw, as you can see you already have a scenario in your rule on a 'creation_date' attribute.  Scenation 'insert' is default scenarion for a new records. There more default scenarions in Yii you can learn at [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/)

Comment: hey thanks for pointing me in the right direction but the part in the action i changed it to if($_POST['Lookup']['type'] == '1') //as I assume from your website '1' is a Movie
    $model->scenario = 'urlcheck'; like that il works